# Cisco 6500 Port Lights

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, cisco-6500

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to change how to port lights function on a 6500 switch.

Most switches work like this...

- No Light - Port in shutdown or no connection
- Solid Orange - Port error (spanning-tree issue, truck issue, etc...)
- Flashing Orange - Duplex error
- Flashing Green - Working

---

On the cisco 6500 it works like this...

- Solid Orange - Port Shutdown
- Flashing Orange - Duplex error
- Flashing Green - Working

Which is fine except I'm colourblind and its extremely difficult to tell the orange apart from the green led so if anyone know of a way to change this it would help be greatly the internet seems to say this is just the way it is but maybe its wrong.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I accepted the one answer its technically correct but doesn't solve the core issue. I solved this by writing a small shell script that runs and shows the port status in the console. Not ideal but better then nothing

Comment: You could post your own answer and accept it if it is more correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say that this isn't a configurable item.